# How to set up simple webserver that supports on and off

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I want to set up a simple Python web server that responds to simple http://localhost:5000/on and http://localhost:5000/off requests. When I say open these URLs in a browser it should run a bash command which I will get working the os component. Could anyone give me some simple code to get this working. Sorry if this is a dumb question but I've only just started using Python. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need a web framework for this. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a popular and simple one.

Comment: Thanks I did some research on Flask and got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with a simple Flask server. This is the code I used:

```
from flask import Flask
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
  return "My Server"

@app.route("/on")
def on():
  os.system("on command")
  return "Device turned on"

@app.route("/off")
def off():
  os.system("off command")
  return "Device turned off"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```